# writing sql query between tables

Tags: sql, database

Which SQL query could I write to satisfiy this need:

**"List the names of the students who take a course from instructor named John."**

[image: schema]

Comment: You can reference attributes from different tables using a '.' ex:
`select Student.FirstName, Instructor.FirstName` etc..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that you can, from the depicted relations.

You can identify tutors by selecting on **InstructorID** and filtering on Instructor.FirstName.

You can join that subset onto course, via the **InstructorCourses** Join Table - join **InstructorID** to that and join the result to **Courses** using **CourseID**

In this way,    *Instructor.InstructorID -> (InstructorCourses.InstructorID , InstructorCourses.CourseID ) -> Courses.CourseID*.

This lets you find information about the courses taught by instructors filtered on their name.

You don't present any link between students and courses in your diagram. I suspect you're missing a relation *StudentCourses*, which ought to be similar to **InstructorCourses**, but rather links students to courses. With that data in the mix, you can extend the join to match students to the courses from the relationship you already have.

Your diagram implies a relation between **Student** and **InstructorCourses**, which seems incorrect -  both because there is no key to join on, and also because the logical relationship would not be correct. I think this is probably an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to satisfy the SQL query you need because your conception does not allow it in that there is no relationship between the 2 tables `Student` and `InstructorCourses`.